# Why does SFC.exe run after each bootup / wake up on all my portable devices with Windows 10 and how can I disable this?

Tags: windows-10

I have 3 physical desktop computers, 1 VM, 1 laptop and 1 tablet running windows 10 x64 1903 fully updated.

The laptop and tablet were always a bit sluggish after boot or waking up, which I attributed to the not so stellar hardware, however I noticed this is in large part due to SFC.exe running each boot or wake up consuming 1 full core for 5-10minutes, bringing the dual core tablet pretty much to a halt. Killing SFC.exe once the task manager manages (ha) to load immediately makes the machine usable.

Manually running sfc /scannow on the machines claims no corrupted files found.

I'm considering writing a short script to kill SFC.exe 10sec after booting in, however I feel this is not something I should have to do.

It is of note, none of the desktops or vm exhibit this behaviour, not even when there actually are corrupted files that sfc /scannow fixes. Only the "portable" devices unfailingly do this every single time they are turned on / woken up.

Answer (score 1):

I was too quick to blame win10 this time. Turns out I happen to use different antivirus solution on desktops / portable devices, and who would've guessed that Cisco's Immunet 6 main process is called sfc.exe as well...